# Azure Advisor API Possible Limitations and Filter Issues

Tags: api, powershell, azure

I manage many subscriptions so the current Azure Advisor while interesting requires you to go through too many screens and there is no way to download the CSV recommendations and compile them using PowerShell. This led to attempt to interface with the API. The issue I am having is that it appears that it limits you to 200 records so changing top does nothing. Many of the records are a generic security warning with a risk of none. I attempted to filter them out but my knowledge of API filters is poor and the documentation Microsoft provides could be better. Below is the PowerShell command I am using:

Call:

```
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${SubscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/Recommendations?api-version=2017-04-19&`$top=999&`$filter=risk -ne None" -Method GET -Headers @{"Authorization" = "$AccessToken"} -Verbose
```

Response:

Without Filter Parameter

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SubID>/providers/microsoft.Advisor/recommendations?api-version=2017-04-19&$top=200&$s
kiptoken=<Token>
```

With Filter Parameter

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${SubscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/Recommendations?api-version=2017-04-19&`$top=999&`$filter=risk -eq 'None'" -Method GET -Headers @{"Authorization" = "$AccessToken"} -Verbose
VERBOSE: GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<sub ID>/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/Recommendations?api-version=2017-04-1
9&$top=999&$filter=risk -eq 'None' with 0-byte payload
Invoke-RestMethod : {"message":"Invalid $filter param"}
At line:1 char:13
+ $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subs ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is  a mistake in your API. The right API grammar is `&$filter` not `$filter`, you could see your API, you lose a `&`.

The following script works for me.

```
##get token
$TENANTID=""
$APPID=""
$PASSWORD=""
$result=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANTID/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Method Post -Body @{"grant_type" = "client_credentials"; "resource" = "https://management.core.windows.net/"; "client_id" = "$APPID"; "client_secret" = "$PASSWORD" }
$token=$result.access_token

##set subscriptionId 
$subscriptionId=""


$Headers=@{
    'authorization'="Bearer $token"
    'host'="management.azure.com"
    'contentype'='application/json'
}
$url="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionID/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/Recommendations?api-version=2017-03-31&`$top=999`&$filter=risk -eq 'None'"


Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $url  -Headers $Headers -Method GET
```

[image]

Comment: If you have a compare tool, you will see the difference clearly. I also use the tool find the difference --).

Comment: My apologies but your answer is not clear. I am using the Advisor API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/advisor/Recommendations/List           I am escaping the $ so Powershell does not process them as a variable. I don't see anywhere where I am losing the & as you say. Should I escape the & and the $? Still not going above 200 records and there is one mistake which is I am using -ne and and not -eq in my filter.

Comment: What is the Compare tool?

Comment: Okay so now I don't get an error but still only 200 rows, I am not sure why that works, and the filter is not working.

Comment: You could example I provied, you don't get the error log, only top 200 rows, it seems Azure limit. I  will check it.

Comment: Well I don't get an error but it still returning None. I appreciate the help but the issue is not resolved. I have a case opened with MS right now.

Comment: @MP Hi, do you check it on Azure Portal, recommendation is null? I updated my answer.

Comment: @MP Do you check on Portal, how many recommendation do you have?

Comment: @MP It seems that we are not in the same time zone. Maybe you could show your result in your question. I will try my best to help you solve it.

Comment: HI  <>
 
Verified with our PG and see that The list recommendations API will provide a next link if there are more than 200 recommendations. So you  can make a query to get the next page and so on until there is no next link. Filtering currently only supports Category and ResourceGroup filters.
 
The ability to get recommendations (and download CSV and PDF) for multiple subscriptions (up to 60 at a time) is now in preview. If you are interested, we can add you to the preview.
 
Let us know if you had any more questions.
 
Best Regards,

Comment: Thank you Walter!

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with exactly the same today, hence I found your article.
I managed to resolve my issue by using a later version of the API, and slightly changing the filter

For example:

```
$filter="Category eq 'Cost'"
$url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$Subscriptionid/providers/microsoft.Advisor/recommendations?api-version=2017-04-19&`$top=999&`$filter=$filter"
```

Comment: I did notice that top=999 does not work, and that 200 seems to be the limit for the API :-(

Comment: Yeah, the API returns a "nextLink" object along with a value payload. I created a while loop invoke-Restmethod those "nextLink" objects and append a variable until there is not one returned to get around the row limit issue. I just wish I could get the actual security advice and not a see our paid service response. If you need most to post a code example I can drop it later.

Comment: Thanks, I did notice the nextlink popping up, makes sense that that contains the additional content :-)
Will keep this in mind myself, for now I am not reaching the limit yet when using the filters.